# weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error creating bean with name 'licenseMapperImpl':

Tags: java, spring-mvc, weblogic, swagger-2.0

getting the below stack trace while deploying war in weblogic

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: Error creating bean with name
>   'licenseMapperImpl': Failed to introspect bean class
>   [springfox.documentation.swagger2.mappers.LicenseMapperImpl]  nested
>   exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/swagger/models/License

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error creating bean with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372859/error-creating-bean-with-name)

Comment: if you use maven try `maven clean` and `maven install`.